# Can the parent view be notified when a child is created

Tags: java, android

In android UI can be created dynamically so is there a way to know if a child was created to a parent ?

For example, if i have a linear layout as a parent and i dynamically create a child button. Is there away to notify the parent ?

Comment: Your question is not very clear, what are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: Why do you want to notify a linear layout that a child was added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple - if you have LinearLayout name linearLayout1, the only why to add child to him is
by calling the linearLayout.addView(View child)  method.
so, you know exactly when the child added:   it's can be only after this method called :)
example:

```
linearLayout1.addView(view);
doWhatYouWantToDoWhenChildAdded();
```

Answer (score 3):

Tal Kanel's version will work, but to avoid repeating code, I'd suggest using a HierarchyChangeListener:

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mylinearlayout);
ll.setOnHierarchyChangeListener(new ViewGroup.OnHierarchyChangeListener() {
    public void onChildViewAdded(View parent, View child) {
        //handle the logic for an added child here
    }    
    public void onChildViewRemoved(View parent, View child) {
        //optionally, handle logic for a removed child
    }
});
```

Comment: your answer seems to me better then mine answer, but not because repeating code issues:   by using the onHierarchyChangeListener  you can be really sure that the child added seccesfully.